# How is a type being narrowed via discriminated union when the discriminator is non specific?

Tags: typescript

Consider an enum:

```
enum TaskType {
  WithId = 'WithId',
  WithValues = 'WithValues',
  WithNothing = 'WithNothing',
}
```

and corresponding classes which use the enum as a discriminator, but does not correctly assign the  `TaskWithId` value:

```
class TaskWithId {
  type: TaskType; // note type is assigned the enum type and not a specific value
  id: number;
}

class TaskWithValues {
  type: TaskType.WithValues; // use specific enum value
  values: number[];
}

class TaskWithNothing {
  type: TaskType.WithNothing; // use specific enum value
}

export type Task = TaskWithId | TaskWithValues | TaskWithNothing;
```

If I use a `switch` to narrow the type, it infers the `TaskWithId` type correctly, despite specifying the discriminator enum incorrectly:

```
switch (task.type) {
    case TaskType.WithId:
      const id = task.id; // task type is inferred as TaskWithId despite non specific discriminator
      break;
  }
```

**How is this 'working'?**

Furthemore, if I try and narrow `TaskWithValues`, it does not work despite using a specific discriminator:

```
 case TaskType.WithValues:
      // const values = task.values; // task type includes TaskWithId, despite specific discriminator
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fkha8n?file=index.ts

Comment: Your code doesn't compile for me on TS Playground.

Comment: It's working logically.  There's an ice cream shop that sells chocolate, vanilla, or strawberry ice cream.  Three children: Charlie, Vanessa, and Quentin, order ice cream.  Charlie orders chocolate and Vanessa orders vanilla.  But you didn't hear what Quentin ordered.  The proprietor brings out one of the orders: it's strawberry.  Whose ice cream is it? It could only be Quentin's. What if instead the proprietor brings out chocolate? Then it's either Quentin's or Charlie's.  That's exactly what's happening with your code. I'm wondering how else you could imagine it going.

Comment: (see prev comment).  Quentin is TaskWithId, if it matters, and strawberry is `TaskType.WithId`.  Does that fully address your confusion or is something still missing?

Comment: Thanks, yeah I see now - it's inferring the `TaskWithId` type because it's the only type left in the union - it can't be the other two as the discriminator doesn't match.

Comment: Right!  So, uh, I guess I'll write that up as an answer when I get a chance?   Maybe without the ice cream 

Comment: Yep, happy to accept it once you put it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the logical consequence of having `TaskWithId`'s `type` property be any of the three `TaskType` values.  Let's have `doSomething()` log both the `Task`'s `type` property as well as its class name:

```
function doSomething(task: Task) {
  console.log("Task type is " + task.type + ", class is " + task.constructor.name);
  switch (task.type) {
    case TaskType.WithId:
      task // (parameter) task: TaskWithId
      const id = task.id;
      break;
    case TaskType.WithValues:
      task // (parameter) task: TaskWithId | TaskWithValues
      break;
  }
}
```

These are all the possible ways you can call `doSomething()`:

```
const taskWithId = new TaskWithId();
taskWithId.type = TaskType.WithId;
doSomething(taskWithId); // ① Task type is WithId, class is TaskWithId
taskWithId.type = TaskType.WithValues;
doSomething(taskWithId); // ② Task type is WithValues, class is TaskWithId
taskWithId.type = TaskType.WithNothing;
doSomething(taskWithId); // ③ Task type is WithNothing, class is TaskWithId
doSomething(new TaskWithValues()); // ④ Task type is WithValues, class is TaskWithValues
doSomething(new TaskWithNothing()); // ⑤ "Task type is WithNothing, class is TaskWithNothing"
```

The `TaskWithValues` and `TaskWithNothing` classes have only a single possible `type`, but `TaskWithId` can be any of the three.  So you've got five possibilities.

Which possibilities correspond to `case TaskType.WithId`?  Only ①, where a `TaskWithId` happens to have a `TaskType.WithId` `type`.  It is impossible for the other two classes to have that `type` value.  So if you are in that `case` block, you can be 100% certain that `Task` is of type `TaskWithId`. And the compiler is also certain of this.

On the other hand, which possibilities correspond to `case TaskType.WithValues`?  Both ②, where a `TaskWithId` happens to have a `TaskType.WithValues` type, and ④, where you have a a `TaskWithValues`.  It is possible for `Task` to be either a `TaskWithId` or a `TaskWithValues`.  So if you are in that `case` block, all you know for sure is that `Task` is not a `TaskWithNothing`. But the other two cases remain, so it's not safe to index into it to get its `values` property.  And again, the compiler knows this.

Obviously the "right" thing to do here is redefine `TaskWithId` so its `type` property the corresponding single literal type `TaskType.WithId`, since the failure to do so leads directly to weird behavior.  But at least the particular weird behavior you see here is *expected* weirdness.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKghgZwNYwJ4AdhQN4CgpQDqAlgC4AWAkgCZQC8UA5CRTYwDT5FnkBqcAGzDAE9Jiz6DhCDlwkA5APYViIAOZjmPJSvWyAvrlwBjAYlHxkEmji6kMwAFyxEKB2MtvMAOmvUA3FAA9EFQIMpY9phQxKLmxGogwLQUWKCQUFFYcCC04aRQcFAImMbEAGbExlAAblLAXMTUzuAQAEbAAE5iAIz+uIYmZggWrhL8QiK2BFnOnmg+4-WiDPMOvjwT0oEhUGAIWCXAZZXV6dB1k1yX0i2QHZ0A2gC6Yi-9g6bmLlbayuSqDR4GYOOauBbADYUHQA9QecHrBT-QE7UL7Q6lCpVKDnWr1AZGLI-JDw36sWgAH2JS0moipniRujU-Vw5TAIGMpGIihAUGoigAyooIMAmQAKUiuMHIACU0ygxh5CEUAkhAkUajFACJPJl3LEoFqoABqTKubxE01a9gK4aiA1G02S5DeRUgBCkTpgTmKTreEBwEUy-oEBAAdzIxnIUAl5qycuBBAViCwa0WPBoji4SbNyGCoTF6DgnUDoq6cudSGlSD82aTbo9MVoDEr3iaIZzUDanWAcCQHYIxhTxIhUMktKzndzJN2heLpdI5en1b8UHpY02yzrBG7vf7XEMnyVBUrq4YSTD1Iz1DFwdwp+vFvcqwR6fJ-X5QpF4of5OD+eJPVogNPwbS+EYYlGMkqGoe8N3JJ9ohfZBRxpbZcE-YVRVhTVfxg-9dl1IkQM3WkwLtSCr3JODoJoRCsGQrxIUZHCP0FLCf3g-DUUA4jRBYwFyO+A0GWvDD2O-HCxQvKjx2kW8CNCIj9X40jpCEiCRK4rYRHEr9sMBaTgEvUToWRdQFJ4nVXCArASLMpkNPtKCaz+JktVwIA)